# How to make a list of 2D 3x3 array and save the ndarray with numpy save?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

So let's say I have some 3x3 matrix I get with a calculation I am doing, let's say

`np.array([[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]])`

`np.array([[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]])`

I want to add this onto some matrix `A` and be able to access them so that if I do

```
> A[0]
> [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]
> A[1]
> [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]]
```

and keep adding on bunch of these 2D array and save them with `np.save('A', A)` for fast access later. I kind of saw it is possible with appending to a list but I can't save a list with `np.save` for fast efficient access. How can I create a empty ndarray I can add matrix onto and save it all as .npy?

Answer (score 1):

You can convert list to array it is the same:

```
A = list()
A.append(x)
A.append(y)
X = np.array(A)
np.save('X', X)
```

Answer (score 0):

Originally use this:

```
A = np.stack((a,b))
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]]
```

And once you have formed `A`, if you want to add another array `c` to `A` use:

```
A = np.vstack((A,[c]))
```

output for `c=a`:

```
[[[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[1 2 3]
  [4 5 6]
  [7 8 9]]]
```